# idangerous swiper: swipe so slow with large list

Tags: android, jquery, ios, slider, swiper.js

I am using idangerous swiper to go to different slides in my app. One of the slide I have list of records, if I have 10 to 20 dynamic records in list, swiper swipe smoothly but as records getting increase it starts swiping quite slow. On my Iphone 4 if I have 300 records it delays like 2 to 3 seconds in swiping to the next slide. I just have these simple line of codes of swiper:

```
window.swiperParent = new Swiper('.swiper-parent', {
        paginationClickable: true,
        mode:'horizontal',
        initialSlide: 1
    });
```

I tried to add speed option but delay still there. Does idangerous swiper not support large number of records?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely too heavy for the rendering engine. And for situations like these we tend to remove slides that are out of view and load slides async with ajax or similiar when they're viewed.